# Where is the documentation on dbt --project-dir option?

Tags: dbt

I'd expect to find it in https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/syntax, but I don't see it.
What I want to know is: does this option simply mean all the sql files under the specified directory including sub-directories.
E.g. Will
dbt run --project-dir /home/dbt/my_project
run every model contained in the *.sql files under this directory?
Windows dbt, version 0.18.1, within a docker container version 20.10.7

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

`--project-dir` should point to the directory where your dbt_project.yml file is located

you can run `dbt run --help` from your terminal

```
  --project-dir PROJECT_DIR
                        Which directory to look in for the dbt_project.yml file. Default is the current working directory and its parents.
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** there is no specific online location where the CLI commands are explicitly documented. Instead, the maintainers of DBT would rather you invoke `dbt --help`.

**Nonetheless, here are several useful documentation references which relate to your Q:**

- [DBT Docs: dbt_project.yml](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt_project.yml)

  > *By default, dbt will look for `dbt_project.yml` in your current working directory and its parents, but you can set a different directory using the --project-dir flag or the `DBT_PROJECT_DIR` environment variable.*
- [DBT Docs: Run your DBT projects](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/running-a-dbt-project/run-your-dbt-projects)

  > *For information on all dbt commands and their arguments (flags), see the dbt command reference. If you want to list all dbt commands from the command line, run `dbt --help`. To list a dbt command’s specific arguments, run `dbt COMMAND_NAME --help`.*
- [DBT Docs: CLI Overview](https://docs.getdbt.com/dbt-cli/cli-overview)

  > *Most command-line tools, including dbt, have a `--help` flag that you can use to show available commands and arguments. For example, you can use the `--help` flag with dbt in two ways: 1)`dbt --help`: Lists the commands available for dbt 2) `dbt run --help`: Lists the flags available for the run command*
- [DBT Docs: Global CLI flags](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/global-cli-flags)

  > *As of v1.0, the vast majority of global CLI flags map to global configs.*
- [DBT Docs: Global configs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/global-configs/about-global-configs)

  > *Starting in v1.0, you can set global configs in three places. When all three are set, command line flags take precedence, then environment variables, and last yaml configs (usually `profiles.yml`).*
- [Helpful Medium Article](https://medium.com/indiciumtech/17-dbt-commands-you-should-start-using-today-581998dbf8f0)